# installing python 2.7.11 on CentOS7 which already has python 2.7.5 is not working

Tags: python-2.7, centos7

CentOS7 has python **2.7.5** by default.

```sh
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

But I needed to use **python 2.7.11**.
So I installed that version from source.

```sh
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz
$ tar xf Python-2.7.11.tgz
$ cd Python-2.7.11

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Output of `which` command have changed.
But python version is still **2.7.5**.

```sh
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

So I want to know why this happened and how to fix this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this like below.

```sh
$ bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf'
$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig
```